# Get Variables Data from two concatenated Strings

Tags: javascript

I want to get the data from the Variable "EDDBGnd".
the debug Paragraph should display "This is a test".

```
var Apt = "EDDB";
var Menu = "Gnd";
var EDDBGnd = "This is a test";

document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML = Apt.concat(Menu);
```

Comment: You could try `window[Apt + Menu]`, assuming `EDDBGnd` is in the global/`window` scope.

Comment: A better option would be to use an object to hold the `EDDBGnd` data, like `var data = {EDDBGnd: "This is a test"};` then you could do `data[Apt + Menu]`.

Comment: See also: [“Variable” variables in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187530/variable-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to scope the global variables to the `window` object.

```js
var Apt = "EDDB";
var Menu = "Gnd";
var EDDBGnd = "This is a test";

document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML =
  window[window.Apt.concat(window.Menu)];
```

```html
<div id="debug"></div>
```

A better way is to create a context or localization file (or object).

```js
const context = {
  'EDDB' : {
    'Gnd': 'This is a test'
  }
};

const Apt = 'EDDB'; // From GUI?
const Menu = 'Gnd'; // From GUI?

const getText = (Apt, Menu) => context[Apt][Menu];

document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML = getText('EDDB', 'Gnd');
```

```html
<div id="debug"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the ability to use a different method to store the data, I would recommend using an object instead. This will allow you to have the apt as a key that can hold multiple menu's for example.

It is more complex, but it will allow you to easily grow the object for more data without messing with variables.

```js
var data = {
  "EDDB": {
    "Gnd": "Test is a test",
    "Gnd2": "Test is also a test",
  }
}

document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML = data["EDDB"]["Gnd"];
document.getElementById("debug2").innerHTML = data["EDDB"]["Gnd2"];
```

```html
<div id="debug"></div>
<div id="debug2"></div>
```

Comment: Have not tryed it, but it should work, but It would sadly not work with my array data structure

Somebody else posted something that works;

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If EDDBGnd is a global variable you can write

```
document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML = window[Apt+Menu];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
document.getElementById("debug").elements[0].value = EDDBGnd;
```